# SailsJs through association - no corresponding attribute in the model error

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Background - I have a list of `Company` records that I'm matching merging into `MergedCompany` records.

I'm attempting to create throughtable / model `CompanyMergedCompany`.

```js
// models/Company.js

  attributes: {

  mergedcompany: {
    collection: 'mergedcompany',
    via: 'companies',
    through: 'companymergedcompany'
  }
}
```

```js
// models/MergedCompany.js

  attributes: {

    companies: {
      collection: 'company',
      via: 'mergedcompany',
      through: 'companymergedcompany`'
    },
}
```

```js
// models/CompanyMergedCompany.js

  attributes: {

   mergedcompany: {
      model: 'mergedcompany'
    },

    company: {
      model: 'company'
    },

}
```

When starting app I'm getting error:

`` error: Failed to lift app: userError: A `through` property was set on the attribute `mergedcompany` on the `company` model but no corresponding attribute in the `mergedcompany` model could be found pointing with the same `through` value (`companymergedcompany`). ``

How to properly create this through association?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your company model

```
 attributes: {

  mergedcompany: {
    collection: 'mergedcompany',
    via: 'company',
    through: 'companymergedcompany'
  }
}
```

You have to give the keys in the "Thorugh Model"(CompanyMergedCompany) in the via option in Company and MergedCompany